# Помогите исправить запрос на удаление всех данных в столбце №2

Tags: c#, mysql

Проблема где то тут

> WHERE COUNT(*) = 2

Могу ли я использовать номер столбца вместо имени столбца

```
MySqlCommand deletedStudentCommand = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM `" + bds + "` WHERE COUNT(*) = 2", sqlConnection);
```

Comment: вы знаете, что за запрос вы написали? А что в условии? А что вы хотели написать? какой результат запроса вы ожидаете?

Comment: @Сергей Мишин нужно удалить данные в столбце 2 -- это не название столбца, а index. Я вот без понятия

Answer (score 0):

Если неизвестно имя поля в таблице, но известен его индекс, то можно взять из таблицы список всех полей следующим запросом:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table_name;
```

Список будет в правильной последовательности. Далее из результата перебором выбираем по нужному индексу название поля и подставляем в ваш запрос на удалении.

P.S. Заодно при поиске имени поля вы узнаете его тип и имеет ли оно значение по умолчанию, что облегчит стирание данных не на произвольное значение, а на дефолтное.

Пример работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Могу ли я использовать номер столбца вместо имени столбца. Мне просто нужно удалить данные столбца №2

Comment: вы имели ввиду так ?                                                                                                
MySqlCommand deletedStudentCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE `" + bds + "` AND ORDINAL_POSITION = '2'", sqlConnection);